# In purescript-dom how do you go from a Node to a specific element type?

Tags: dom, purescript, halogen

I think I might be missing a key function in the `purescript-dom` module to convert from a Node to a specific element type.  For instance if I have a `Event`, I can use DOM.Events.Events.target to get the Node, but it seems like the only way to get a specific element is with `unsafeCoerce`, e.g.

```
import DOM.Event.Event (target)
import DOM.HTML.HTMLInputElement (value)

eval (InputChange event next) = do
  -- Get the value of the HTMLInputElement assuming it is one
  v <- H.liftEff $ value (unsafeCoerce $ target event)
  H.liftEff $ log "Input field change"
  H.liftEff $ log v
  pure next
```

Is there a better way to go from a Node to an element type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to use `toForeign` and then `readHTMLInputElement` when you want to upcast a `Node` / element type.

It's pretty annoying to constantly write things like that though, so [`purescript-dom-classy`](https://github.com/garyb/purescript-dom-classy) aims to take some of the pain out of it. As well as avoiding the `toForeign` step you'll only have a `Maybe` to deal with, rather than the `Except` a `read` function will return.